# Predict type of device with Keras using time series data

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have date/time and the corresponding energy consumption of different devices (data series of current energy consumption).
I want to have a neural network that can determine the type of device from a data set.

Example of the data:

```
15.05.2012  16:59:48    4   2
15.05.2012  16:59:53    4   2
15.05.2012  16:59:57    2   2
15.05.2012  17:00:02    2   2
15.05.2012  17:00:07    2   2
15.05.2012  17:00:11    4   87
15.05.2012  17:00:15    676 171
15.05.2012  17:00:20    2   87
```

So far I could not find anything online on how to proceed in such a case.

Comment: What the last and last but one column mean? Which energy consumption is represented by these 2 columns?

Comment: The two columns on the right are the power consumption readings averaged over time durations of one and eight seconds.

Comment: Thomas, do you have training set? It's the set where the device types are known for every power consumption sample. If yes, it's typical approximation you should examine feedforward networks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network)

Comment: Yes I have many sets of training data (known device, day long measurement as one file).